# Rewrite category and subcategory with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A former directory naming convention produced the following:

```
www.mysite.com/oldcategory/oldsubcategory/page1.html
www.mysite.com/oldcategory/oldsubcategory/page2.html
www.mysite.com/oldcategory/oldsubcategory/page3.html
...etc.
```

The directories have been renamed, so I need to rewrite the above as:

```
www.mysite.com/newcategory/newsubcategory/page1
www.mysite.com/newcategory/newsubcategory/page2
www.mysite.com/newcategory/newsubcategory/page3
...etc.
```

I already have a rewrite rule for '.html', but I'm not sure how to rewrite the directory names.

Also, it's worth noting that I have several file rewrite rules in the htaccess file already. I'm mentioning this in the event that rules for the directory rewrites must be placed above or below that file rewrite rules.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the new category and subcategory the same for all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rewrite rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^oldcategory/oldsubcategory/([^.]+)\.html$ newcategory/newsubcategory/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I applied it, but it does not work. However, I'm wondering about this portion: \.html$. I already have a statement that removes the html -- does this intend to do the same thing? If so, would this be a valid rewrite: RewriteRule ^oldcategory/oldsubcategory/([^.]) newcategory/newsubcategory/$1 [L,NC,R=301]. Sorry, i just don't know much about writing these rules.

Comment: This rule needs to be your first rule and should be placed before other existing rules.